# Answer previews in mobile web SE pages

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, markdown-preview

Unless I am blind, the mobile web editor does not offer a preview of an answer, unlike the desktop web and Android application which do.

I would use the Android application (which I like) for the previews, but its MathJax is reportedly outdated and is not compatible with all SE sites due to site extensions, like `\pu` from mhchem at the Chemistry SE site.

Could the preview be implemented for the mobile web version as well? Perhaps similarly like in the application as the switching links, maybe among the link list at the page bottom.

Comment: Sorry, I have tried to find any, not to create duplicate, but probably not hard enough. I was strange, indeed, that nobody would ask...

Comment: Thank for editing, but it could be too much effort for just a duplicate. :-)

Comment: @awizardarachnid Keep in mind that edits within five days push questions into the reopen queue, where reviewers by default see the edit. Making minor grammar edits to such questions is bad for three reasons: 1. it creates extra work for other users who have to dismiss the resulting review tasks, 2. since by default users are shown the edit diff, even if the question is reopenable on its own users will only see a minor edit and review as "Leave Closed", and 3. even if the question is not reopenable on its own, it deprives the post author or others to have the post reopened by editing.